# VBA script to copy range of cell contents to clipboard without quotation mark

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to use a VBP script to copy cell contents from range E24 to E90 without quotation mark.

This is the script I have found and modified from the Internet. It drops me a "Type mismatch" error when I set the range E24:E90, with one cell it works fine, but I would need to copy a range of contents in one go.

```
Dim doClip As DataObject
Dim sText As String
Dim rCell As Range, rRow As Range
Dim rSrc As Range

Set doClip = New DataObject
Set rSrc = Range("E24:E90")
doClip.SetText rSrc
doClip.PutInClipboard
Set doClip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can you help me fixing it?

This is the sheet which works with variables. I'd like to copy all the cells without quotation mark starting from cell E24 to E90.

[image: This is the sheet I would like to copy the cells from.]

Comment: I can't test this in VBA because DataOBject isn't defined. This suggests that when you have a visual basic project file there may be other dependencies set up in it https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/opening-a-visual-basic-project-with-excel.74310/

Comment: You'll see from Help that DataObject doesn't work like that. Why are you not directly copying and pasting?

Comment: Because I am having a function merging variables in merged cells. Quotation marks also not needed as that would fragment the txt file I paste it from Excel. This is the only way it worked for me, only the range I can't make it work. Just copy of single cells work unfortunately.
I have this one as well, but with this quotation marks and line breaks stay unfortunately:
Sub copy2clipboard()
    Range("E24:E90").Copy
End Sub

Comment: Would really help your question to include a screenshot of source data and how it should look when pasted (are you pasting in Excel?)

Comment: Added a link to download an Example, thanks.

Comment: Please provide mock-up data or a screenshot.  It is typically frowned upon to have a downloadable, and as habit and as suggested by some bigger folks, it is recommended to any person answering questions to *not* download anything from the site.

Comment: Sorry for me being so lame, this is my first topic here. :)
I have added the picture hopefully it makes sense now.